# How do I differentiate between units and variables on my notebook?

Tags: soft-question, notation

On computer systems, variables are written in italics, as $m$ or $s$, and the units as $\mathrm{m}$ or $\mathrm{s}$. It is very incovenient to do italics for variables and upright for units while writing by hand. We usually denote the variables by using upright letters. This can lead to confusion, especially in equations where you want to show the units too, and there are variables present also.

As a make-shift solution, i give serifs to the letters in a unit (like two horizontal lines below n and two below m, etcetera).

What are some ways to differentiate unit symbols and variables while writing by hand?

Comment: Context tells you the difference in so many cases than most people I know *don't* have any kind of typographical convention in their handwritten material.

Comment: It is usual and good practice to keep units, numbers and values out of the expression as long as there are still unknown variables present. Of this reason I've never experienced this as a problem

Comment: @dmckee Well I am a little obsessive about being consistent in my notation everywhere (example, I always use $\ln$ for natural log, everywhere. Granted, all this is unnecessary, but I wanted to know just in case if anyone had a good idea...otherwise, I'll take your and Steeven's advice! Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about proper handwriting, not physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I suspected that someone would. Is there an SE site where I can actually ask this?

Comment: @FreezingFire It would fit well in [chat], but I'm not sure of an SE site that wants this type of question. _Maybe_ [lifehacks.SE] but you would have to check with them.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for the suggestion! I found a way anyways...I'll post better questions next time! :P

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea to keep units out of your expressions for as long as possible. If you do that you are unlikely to run into trouble.

Still, if you do have issues, you can just come up with you own typographic conventions if the notes are just for yourself. For instance, you could always keep your units to the far right and put curly backets or something around them e.g.
\begin{equation}
F = \frac{37.0}{t^2}\{kg*m\}
\end{equation}